# How to echo specific data from Wikipedia API json response?

Tags: php, json, wikipedia-api

I am trying to echo the array values in a string readable format in PHP. Iam getting the data from wikipedia in a json format which is been converted to array. I need this in a readable string format. But am getting error.

```
 <?php
 $url=file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Haw%20Par%20Villa&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json");
 $decode=json_decode($url,true);
 $slice=array_slice($decode, 1);
 $content=array_values($slice['query']['pages'])[0]['revisions'][0]['*'];
 echo $content;
?>
```

Can anyone help me on the same.

Following is the result achieved from echo $content
[image]

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: Share how you need to display and what you need to display

Comment: @Nair. Even am from kerala. i am trying to get the details about a particular place or location from wikipedia. When you pass the title to the API you get the response in json format. When i echo $content i am getting the data. But i need to convert this to a string readable format. Iam not sure if i need to use for each loop or directly i can read the content.

Comment: @Tom. Iam getting the following error. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: What is the result of `echo $content;` ?

Comment: i have attached the image to the question with the result of echo $content;

Comment: $url=file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Haw%20Par%20Villa&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json");
$decode=json_decode($url,true);
$slice=array_slice($decode, 1);
$content=array_values($slice['query']['pages']);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($content[0]['revisions']);

Comment: @Sachin. Now the result is in array. I need to display about the place (content) in a normal readable format.

Comment: The API response is in Json format: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Haw%20Par%20Villa&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json

Comment: are you want * ??

Comment: `$content` is a string, not an array.  You cannot iterate it in its current form.  What is your exact expected output from the data in your image? If you do not clarify, the question may be closed as _Unclear what you are asking_.

Comment: @Sachin. I didnt get you.

Comment: Please let me know exact output.

Comment: @Sachin. I need to get the content about How Par Villa in this context. The text you can see "How Par Villa is a themepark located along.... "

Answer (score 0):

$content is a string where you trying to access it as an object, Here ['revisions'][0] clearly specify that the value is string rather than being an object/array.

contentformat = text/x-wiki and contentmodel = wikitext where as * has the response data for your request.

Comment: Yes i understand. Iam trying to get the text (content).  I need to get the content about How Par Villa in this context. The text you can see "How Par Villa is a themepark located along....